# I need to migrate a jee jsf application from jboss eap 6.3 to wildfly 8.2.1

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have errors related to jsf, in jboss EAP the application works perfectly, when I change the JSF @ManagedBean and @SessionScoped annotations per @named and @SessionScoped of the CDI works, but vision bugs appear

Is there any incompatibility between these servers that I should know about?

Here's the stacktrace of the error

```
    SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-14) Error Rendering View[/sistema/index.xhtml]: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /sistema/templates/menu.xhtml @27,267 rendered="#{menuBB.acessoMenuIncluirEditorial.rendered or menuBB.acessoMenuIncluirPapelaria.rendered or menuBB.acessoMenuIncluirProntoAtendimento.rendered }": The class 'java.lang.Boolean' does not have the property 'acessoMenuIncluirEditorial'.
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:457)
        at org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeElements(TieredMenuRenderer.java:99)
        at org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeMenu(TieredMenuRenderer.java:79)
        at 
...
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:655)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
        at br.gov.camara.cotasgraf.controle.util.SelecaoSolicitanteFiltro.doFilter(SelecaoSolicitanteFiltro.java:58)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
        at br.gov.camara.cotasgraf.controle.util.EncodeFiltro.doFilter(EncodeFiltro.java:38)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
        at br.gov.camara.cotasgraf.controle.util.CacheFiltro.doFilter(CacheFiltro.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.Boolean' does not have the property 'acessoMenuIncluirEditorial'.
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:731)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:351)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstOr.getValue(AstOr.java:58)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstOr.getValue(AstOr.java:58)
        at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
        at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
        at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
        ... 73 more
    
    2021-12-06 14:36:36,278 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-14) UT005023: Exception handling request to /cotasgraf/sistema/index.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException: /sistema/templates/menu.xhtml @27,267 rendered="#{menuBB.acessoMenuIncluirEditorial.rendered or menuBB.acessoMenuIncluirPapelaria.rendered or menuBB.acessoMenuIncluirProntoAtendimento.rendered }": The class 'java.lang.Boolean' does not have the property 'acessoMenuIncluirEditorial'.
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:667)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
        at br.gov.camara.cotasgraf.controle.util.SelecaoSolicitanteFiltro.doFilter(SelecaoSolicitanteFiltro.java:58)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
        at br.gov.camara.cotasgraf.controle.util.EncodeFiltro.doFilter(EncodeFiltro.java:38)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
        at br.gov.camara.cotasgraf.controle.util.CacheFiltro.doFilter(CacheFiltro.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /sistema/templates/menu.xhtml @27,267 rendered="#{menuBB.acessoMenuIncluirEditorial.rendered or menuBB.acessoMenuIncluirPapelaria.rendered or menuBB.acessoMenuIncluirProntoAtendimento.rendered }": The class 'java.lang.Boolean' does not have the property 'acessoMenuIncluirEditorial'.
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:457)
        at org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeElements(TieredMenuRenderer.java:99)
        at org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeMenu(TieredMenuRenderer.java:79)
        at org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeMarkup(TieredMenuRenderer.java:58)
        at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(BaseMenuRenderer.java:113)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
        at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
        at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:84)
        at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:71)
        at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:86)
        at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:71)
        at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:49)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:655)
        ... 44 more
    Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.Boolean' does not have the property 'acessoMenuIncluirEditorial'.
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:731)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:351)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstOr.getValue(AstOr.java:58)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstOr.getValue(AstOr.java:58)
        at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
        at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
        at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
        ... 73 more
```

Comment: From the stacktrace the `menuBB` variable seems bound to a Boolean, can you post your template (the relevant part) or analyze how is defined that bean. Maybe you just need to specify something like `@Named("menuBB")`, to that class, the default annotation could define a MenuBB class as menuBb bean.

Comment: Review the object "acessoMenuIncluirProntoAtendimento" in your bean "menuBB" and check if the "rendered" property (which must be a boolean) has been defined and it has the getter/setter methods to retrieve this value.

Comment: the method it calls on that screen is from the UIComponent class
 public abstract boolean isRendered();

Comment: Since `The class 'java.lang.Boolean' does not have the property 'acessoMenuIncluirEditorial'` and you're using `menuBB.acessoMenuIncluirEditorial` that means it's resolving `menuBB` as a `Boolean`, so check if it's definition is correct (print in a blank page `#{menuBB}`) and try to add/define the bean as `@Named("menuBB")`

Comment: I will make this attempt. why does it work on jboss eap 6 and not on wildfly?

with '@Named'
and
'@SessionScoped'
of the CDI partially works.
The other screens are still buggy. For example, Ajax doesn't work